# How to create Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> from PropertyInfo in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, expression

I created a repository which wraps EntityFrameworkCore's repositories. In my repository, I have a method named `Include` which must add a `Where` clause to the relation if the related model implements the `ISoftDelete` interface.

After the clause is added, I want to create `Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>` so I can pass my own expression to EntityFrameworkCore's Include method.

Here is my code

```
public interface ISoftDelete
{
    public DateTime? Deleted { get; set;}
}

public class Repository<TModel>
{
    //... Other repository methods removed

    public IQueryable<TEntity> Include(string propertyName)
    {
        // find the property of the current model by the given property name
        var property = typeof(TModel).GetProperty(propertyName);

        if (property == null)
        {
            throw new Exception($"The property name '{propertyName}' does not exists.");
        }

        Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> exp = null;

        // Get the value of the property/relation
        var value = property.GetValue(this);

        if (value is IEnumerable<ISoftDelete> collection)
        {
            var clause = collection.Where(r => !r.Deleted.HasValue).AsQueryable();

            // set the exp from the clause
        }
        else if (value is ISoftDelete soft)
        {
            // apply where clause
            // if soft is deleted I don't want to include it!
            // create the where clause and set exp
        }
        else
        {
            // invoke the property without any clause
            exp = model => model.GetType().InvokeMember(property.Name, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, model, null);
        }

        // finally pass the expression to Entity

        return Context.Set<TEntity>().Include(exp);
    }
}
```

Question: how can I create the `Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>` expression in the above method?

Comment: Why do you need that?  EF supports `Include` from property name. Probably you have missed this [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) . You can define global filter for Soft deleted records.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I am aware of that. What I am trying to do here is always add a clause if the Entity implements `ISoftDelete`. For that reason, I want to first apply the clause then pass that expression to entity-core

Comment: As I understand, you are trying to dynamically build [filtered include](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include). It's possible, but only for collection navigation properties, since EF Core does not offer a way to define filtered include for reference navigation properties. That's why adding global query filter for each entity implementing `ISoftDeletable` is a better (and for references - the only) solution, since EF Core will add it to *any* query accessing the entity table, including those produced by `Include` / `ThenInclude` statements.